# VIM returns "Error detected while processing" and "Sorry, the command is not available in this version"

Tags: ubuntu, psql

When I run VIM with `\e` inside of `psql`, I get

```
Error detected while processing /home/ecarroll/.vimrc:
line   11:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

However I don't get this error outside of PSQL. Further visual block mode in VIM doesn't work when I try to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Single-User Solution

Run `select-editor` and select the proper version of vim. This is what `psql` does on initial run. This will drop a file `~/.selected_editor` which will be used by `psql` when it calls `sensible-editor`.

## Multi-User Ubuntu/Debian

If you're on Debian it's best to set it system-wide, especially if you're the only user on the system.

- Have `psql` delegate to the system. To configure `psql` to use your default editor, run

  ```
  echo SELECTED_EDITOR="editor" > ~/.selected_editor
  ```
- Configuring Debian and Ubuntu system-wide for the right editor, simply run

  ```
  update-alternatives --config editor
  ```

  Or set it your self,

  ```
  update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
  ```

## Checking

You can always check what version of vim you're using by issuing `:version`, this should say something like this

```
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.
```

If it doesn't, and it instead says

```
Huge version without GUI.
```

Or,

```
Small version without GUI.
```

You're likely without the needed features. Visual block replace specifically requires `-vreplace`

Comment: <rant> "This will drop a file ~/.selected_editor which will be used by psql when it calls sensible-editor" - And lo, there appeared to the assembled masses yet another file in the home directory of the believer as if inspired by the Divine Being, the Almighty or <whatever_your're_having_yourself...>, a file entitled "~/.<yet_another_effing_file_whose_meaning_I'll_have_forgotten_in_10_minutes...>". Those who worship at the altar of the one true OS are falling off the holy path with the diabolical proliferation of such idolatrous artefacts - "Oh my Lord, why hast thou forsaken me?" </rant> :-)

Comment: BUT WHAT IF GRANDMA WANTS TO LOG IN AND CONNECT TO `psql` WITH A DEFAULT EDITOR THAT IS NOT THE SYSTEM DEFAULT?!?!?!!???????

Comment: No need to shout! :-) I'm not objecting to config files (and the benefits of personalised settings), I'm just objecting to the Linux fetish for "decorating" your home directory with gazillions of `~/.<whatever(rc)>` files.What **I** would like to see is a) **single** directory (in /home/me) with the files there - or possibly a tree) and b) have a default mechanism for adding a comment - i.e. when one of these abominations (`:-)`) is created,you should be dropped into your favourite editor (as determined by a ~/.favourite_editor?) to put in a line or two explaining what the file is configuing!